# How to send request from Express server to another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I am trying to fetch data from Express server from another external server.

That is search api, which is post request and I am from client get body params.

Then try to send that params on another server:
`http://search-api.com/d/explore?`

```
public static async search(req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) {
    try {
      const data = await axios.post(
        `http://search-api.com/d/explore?user_id=${
          req.body.id
        }`,
        {
          query: req.body.query,
          topics: req.body.topics
        }
      );

      res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
      ErrorHandler.handle('Error fetching search response.', err, res);
    }
  }
```

This is response Error:

> [ERROR] default - "Error fetching search response."
>   Error: Request failed with status code 422

I was check params exist and they are ok.

Does anyone have idea what can be the problem here?

**UPDATED**:

This is how body of request should looks:
[image]

Comment: Is the 4 w's in `wwww.search-api.com` for real or a mistake?

Comment: "I was check params exist and they are ok." — Are they? Does the server have the right body parser?

Comment: You should log the query on the search API and the response at this end to see what is being returned.

Comment: What format does the API expect the body to be, and what does Axios send?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forgot about `http://` protocol on beginning; also, you have `wwww` instead of `www`, but I assume that it's just dummy text there:

```
public static async search(req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) {
try {
  const data = await axios.post(
    `http://www.search-api.com/d/explore?user_id=${
      req.body.id
    }`,
    {
      query: req.body.query,
      topics: req.body.topics
    }
  );

  res.send(data);
 } catch (err) {
   ErrorHandler.handle('Error fetching search response.', err, res);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is a search API maintained by yourself, or it is an external API? 422 HTTP error is telling that a request is not understood by server, i.e. when incorrect `Content-Type` is passed. Does the server understand `application/json` payload (which is used by default in `axios`, or maybe it requires regular form data? https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: If the URL would be wrong, this would likely return a 404 or 500, but probably never a 422

Comment: I am not saying about URL, I am saying about POST payload: `{ query: req.body.query, topics: req.body.topics }`

Comment: I updated the post with screenshot of how body of req should looks. 
Only `query` is required field.

Comment: @DawidRusnak maybe problem is `topics` it should be array not string

Comment: Are you passing a string instead of array then? Probably you should do it like in documentation, using an array

Comment: When I test the api via Swager, I see the request url have different `email`, `nikola.trajkovic%40tamedia.ch` - There is no monkey. Maybe that is problem?